# Pandas Manipulate Multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do some dataframe manipulation.  How can I take a dataframe like

```
2018 data

Age   City1    City2
0         5        10
1         6        11
2         8        21


2019 data

Age   City1    City2
0         15        20
1         63        21
2         83        41
```

and make separate dataframes like

```
Age 0 
       2018    2019
City1     5      15
City2    10      20 

Age 1 
       2018    2019
City1     6      63
City2    11      21 

Age 2 
       2018    2019
City1     8      83
City2    21      41
```

To make the dataframe

```
df1 = {'Age': [0,1,2], 'City1': [5,6,8], 'City2': [10,11,22]}

df2 = {'Age': [0,1,2], 'City1': [15,63,83], 'City2': [10,11,41]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for information about years, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Age'), df2.set_index('Age')], keys=(2018, 2019), axis=1).stack()
print (df)
         2018  2019

0 City1     5    15
  City2    10    10
1 City1     6    63
  City2    11    11
2 City1     8    83
  City2    22    41
```

If need select each `DataFrame` from `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df.loc[0])
print (df.xs(0))
       2018  2019
City1     5    15
City2    10    10

print (df.loc[1])
print (df.xs(1))

       2018  2019
City1     6    63
City2    11    11
```

If need create dictionary of `DataFrame`s loop by `groupby` object:

```
d = {k: v.reset_index(level=0, drop=True) for k, v in df.groupby(level=0)}
print (d)
{0:        2018  2019
City1     5    15
City2    10    10, 1:        2018  2019
City1     6    63
City2    11    11, 2:        2018  2019
City1     8    83
City2    22    41}
```

Comment: @OptimusPrime - it is [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select by `MultiIndex`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Age` as index and use `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df_dicts = {2018:df1, 2019:df2}

df = pd.DataFrame({k:v.set_index('Age').stack() for k,v in df_dicts.items()})
```

gives you a double indexed dataframe:

```
           2018  2019
Age                  
0   City1     5    15
    City2    10    10
1   City1     6    63
    City2    11    11
2   City1     8    83
    City2    22    41
```

And you can access data for each `Age` by, e.g. `df.loc[0]`, which gives:

```
    2018    2019
City1   5   15
City2   10  10
```